# Differential problem, how to get y''?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, implicit-differentiation

I've the following equation: $b^2x^2 + a^2y^2 = a^2b^2$, the first implicit derivative is:

$\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{-b^2x}{a^2y}$

I do not undertand how to find the second derivative of this equation, could someone guide me ?

Ps: I guess the second derivative is:
$\dfrac{d}{dx}(\dfrac{-b^2x}{a^2y}) = \dfrac{b^2*(x-y)}{a^2y^2}$, but isn't right.

Is it the right asnwer: $\dfrac{(-a^2b^2y^2) - (b^4x^2)}{(a^4y^3)}$ ?

Comment: Differentiate on both sides the expression you have for the first derivative of $y$. You'll have an equation with a $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$. Just substitute the value you have for the first derivative.

If you're having doubts on how to differentiate the quotient, check out the derivative properties, it's not hard.

Comment: "Just substitute the value", sorry but what value ?

Comment: The one you already have, $\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{-b^2x}{a^2y}$

Comment: I eddited the post, count youi answer me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's best to differentiate implicitly twice. If $b^2x^2 + a^2y^2 = a^2b^2$ then
$$2b^2x+2a^2yy' = 0$$
$$2b^2 + 2a^2(y')^2 + 2a^2yy'' = 0$$
As you have done: solve $2b^2x+2a^2yy' = 0$ for $y'$.

Substitute your expression for $y'$ into $2b^2 + 2a^2(y')^2 + 2a^2yy'' = 0$ and solve for $y''$.

**Note:** Your guess at the second derivative doesn't work because $y$ is a function of $x$. If you have
$$y' = -\frac{b^2}{a^2}\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)$$
then differentiating with respect to $x$ gives (by applying the quotient rule)
$$y'' = -\frac{b^2}{a^2}\left(\frac{y-xy'}{y^2}\right)$$

Comment: Can you see my answer on the question? Is it right ?

Comment: @mastergoo It looks right to me. Although you don't need so many brackets. Don't forget to up-vote answers that you found helpful (click the up-arrows) and remember to select the most helpful answer (click the tick).

Answer (score 0):

$$b^2x^2 + a^2y^2 = a^2b^2 \Rightarrow \frac{b^2}{a^2} = \frac{b^2 - y^2}{x^2}$$

Then:

$$\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{-b^2x}{a^2y} = -\frac{(b^2-y^2)x}{x^2y} = \frac{y^2-b^2}{xy}$$

At this point, you can separate variables:

$$dy \frac{y}{y^2-b^2} = dx \frac{1}{x}$$

Integrating...

$$\int_{y_0}^y \frac{t}{t^2-b^2} dt = \int_{x_0}^x\frac{1}{s}ds$$
$$\frac{1}{2}\int_{y_0}^y \frac{2t}{t^2-b^2} dt = \log(x) - \log(x_0)$$
$$\frac{1}{2}[\log(y^2-b^2) - \log(y_0^2 -b^2)] = \log(x) - \log(x_0)$$
$$\frac{1}{2}\log(y^2-b^2) = \log\left(\frac{x}{x_0}\right) + \frac{1}{2}\log(y_0^2 -b^2)$$
$$\log(\sqrt{y^2-b^2}) = \log\left(\frac{x\sqrt{y_0^2-b^2}}{x_0}\right) $$
$$\sqrt{y^2-b^2} = \left(\frac{x\sqrt{y_0^2-b^2}}{x_0}\right) $$
$$y^2 = \left(\frac{x\sqrt{y_0^2-b^2}}{x_0}\right) + b^2$$
$$y(x) = \sqrt{\left(\frac{x\sqrt{y_0^2-b^2}}{x_0}\right) + b^2}$$

where

$$y(x_0) = y_0$$